# File Upload and download JavaScript

Tags: reactjs

**EDIT**

Hope someone can clarify this issue I am having:

I want to store files in the backend inBinary format, and after get them and convert them into the original state of the file, I believe there is something wrong with my code, I am using HTML upload

this is how I send the binary data to backend:

```
  const handleSubmit = async file => {
    let formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', file)
    try {
      const res = await postInvoice(uuid, formData)
      console.log(res)
      setLoadingInvoice(false)
      setState({
        fileList: [],
        attachments: [],
        filesConverted: [],
      })
    }
  }
**edit with the api call, only missing hte url part which is in a different file**
export const postInvoice = async (id, data) => {
  return await request
    .post(BRattachments().post(id))
    .send(data)
    .set(getHeaders())
}
```

this is how I try to download te bianrry data:

```
const handleDownload = async value => {
    try {
      const res = await getInvoice(value.id)//api call
      
      const file = new Blob([response], {
        type: res.type,
      })
      saveAs(file, value.id + '.' + res.extension)//using save as to save import saveAs from 'file-saver'

    }
  }

**edited,this is the API CALL,I have them groued in a different file**
export const getInvoice = async ref => {
  return await request
    .get(BRattachments().getAll(ref))
    .send()
    .set(getHeaders())
    .responseType('blob')
}
```

the problem is that every time I try to download any saved file, it gives me a problem, with XLS I only see null in the file, with PNG it says file not PNG, etc.

Hope someone can clarify how can I download binary file and convert it in a downloadable file.

thanks

Comment: is the blob valid? did your backend send u the correct file?

Comment: what is getInvoice, it's a fetch? did u capture the correct object?

Comment: I updated the post with the info requested, I hope it clarifies

Comment: const res = await getInvoice(value.id) <- did u console.log(res), as well as check your network tab (preview) to see if it return the value u want?

Comment: since u say the file is null, kindly troubleshoot whether it's a frontend or backend issue.

Comment: Hi everyone, I am checking the backend with the backend guys, I believe that there can be an issue there, the response I get when uploading the info is succesful, I am sending in the body of the request the binary file; the problem is when downloading later the same file, I get unespecified filetype, I believe at some point hte information is mismatching, anyway thanks guys, you helped me make sure that the frontend is correct and it is the correct way tot send binary data

Comment: finllay it loooks like a backend issue, they were not able to verify the file type, so in frontend I was already wrongly the info